# How to use English word package flutter in android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, package

imported :`import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';`
how can I used this package words inside my program and functions?
it is just available in my Main() function.

Comment: did you add it on `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Sample : https://aresune.com/?_=%2Fcodelabs%2Ffirst-flutter-app-pt1%23%2F57C5UEu5oZLs3J3NHcWtzQI44JLKSPPwoyXb%2Fw97br7j5j2XXk%3D

Comment: yes I did my friend. and I'm using it in my testing program. but I have access to just first and last word. how can i have the others?